# Xamarin error deploying app on device INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS

Tags: c#, android, debugging, xamarin.android

When I try to deploy an app on android device I'm getting an error.

Output log:

> Build succeeded.
>   2>An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
>   2>Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_23 without first uninstalling.]
>   2>

I have uninstalled Mono.Android.Platform multiple times from my device, it did not helped.

Comment: did u manually delete the old version of the application on the device before attempting to reinstall it?

Comment: Yes, I did, no files left, or visible through the App manager->All

Comment: Well, all I can say after the last 4 months of intermittently working on Xamarin is GOOD LUCK! If you arent required to use it because of the client i would highly suggest you ditch xamarin. In my experience it is nothing but nightmare after nightmare. You will spend 90% of dev time fixing xamarin specific problems instead of fixing problems with your actual code.

Comment: Try using `Settings - Aps - YourProject.Android - Menu on the top at the right - Uninstall for all users - Accept`.

Comment: What is your app package name?

Comment: com.app.app1.apk

Comment: I don't know what to do... one moment it worked just fine and now i'm unable to use debugger :/